# Git branch name change committed but not push to origin

Tags: git, github

1. Created a new branch, for example `branch-1`
2. Changed the code and committed but not pushed
3. Renamed branch to `branch-2` and code changed and committed.
4. Pushed the changes to git

Does the pushed branch is named as `branch-1` or `branch-2`?

Comment: What is your git command for task "Rename branch to branch-2"?

Comment: What command did you use to push the branch ?

Comment: I used `git push origin master`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full answer is a little bit long, but the short answer based on your comment:

> I used `git push origin master`

is that you have not pushed anything other than `master` anyway, so none of these other branch names has been involved at all.

#### The long answer

It's worth starting out with this: the syntax for `git push` is:

`git push remote refspec1 refspec2 ... refspecN`

That is, the word `origin` in your command is a *remote*, and the word `master` is a *refspec* (and you used exactly one such refspec, although you are allowed to push more than one refspec).

The *remote* argument here is simply the name of what Git calls a *remote*, which I admit is a circular definition and not very useful.  But we can define it by example: `origin` is a remote, and in most cases, `origin` is your *only* remote.  So the third word in `git push origin ...` is always `origin` anyway.  The only time you would write anything different here is if you add more remotes, using [git remote add (click link to see its documentation)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html).

The more interesting part is the refspec.  A *refspec* is, in its second-simplest form, just a pair of names—usually branch names—separated by a colon, such as `master:master`.  The name on the left side of the colon is the *source reference*, and the name on the right side is the *destination reference*.  If you write:

```
git push origin master:master
```

you are asking your Git to call up another Git, at the URL stored under the name `origin`, and have your Git ask their Git to set *their* `master`—the `:master` part—the same way you set your own `master`, the `master:` part of `master:master`.

I said this is the *second* simplest form, because the *simplest* form is just to write your own branch name.  When you do this, Git assumes—for `git push` at least—that you want to set the *same* name on the other side, so that `master` is just short for `master:master`.

If you wish to have your Git ask their Git to set *their* `branch-2`, you must put something other than `master` in the refspec.  For instance, you could run:

```
git push origin branch-2:branch-2
```

to ask their Git to set their `branch-2` based on your `branch-2`.  You could abbreviate this by leaving out the `:branch-2` part.  Note that you can also do:

```
git push origin master:branch-2
```

which asks their Git to set their `branch-2` based on your `master`, rather than your `branch-2`!

If you do any of these, you will find some other interesting aspects of `git push`.  Specifically:

- Your own Git has a configuration setting, `push.default`, which (if your Git is not too ancient) defaults to `simple`.
- If your `push.default` is set to `simple`, Git "wants" to push `master` to `master` and `branch-2` to `branch-2`.  (If your `push.default` is set to other values, Git has different things it will enforce.)
- The `simple` setting means that you can just run `git push`, *provided* you set the *upstream* for each of your branches.

  ```
  git push
  ```

  will take the *current* branch's upstream setting, whatever that is, and use that to `git push` to a branch of the *same name* on the appropriate remote.

To make this last bit work, you need the upstream of the branch name `master` to be `origin/master`, and the upstream of the branch name `branch-2` to be `origin/branch2`.  So, what exactly is an *upstream?*

#### The upstream setting of a branch name

Each branch can have one (1) upstream.  A branch may start out with no upstream at all.  The upstream actually consists of two parts, for historical reasons, but you can set it with:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/branch2 branch2
```

for instance, to set the upstream of `branch2` to `origin/branch2`.

Typically, the upstream for any branch named *X* is `origin/X`.  The `simple` setting for `push.default` *requires* this kind of matching name, which means that if you rename a branch, you must also change its upstream (if it had one before).

There's a wrinkle in setting the upstream of a branch, especially right after you have just created it.  You just created `branch-2`—well, technically, you created `branch-1` and then renamed it to `branch-2`, but this amounts to the same thing—so the Git over at `origin` *does not have a branch named `branch-2` yet*.  This means your own Git does not have an `origin/branch-2` yet, since your Git's `origin/*` names are your Git's way of remembering what their Git has, and their Git doesn't have this yet.

What this boils down to is that after you create a branch, the *first time* you push it, you *must* spell out the full push:

```
git push origin branch-2
```

for instance, or:

```
git push origin branch-2:branch-2
```

if you want to be totally explicit about it.  *Once you have done that*, you can then use `git branch --set-upstream-to`:

```
git push origin branch-2
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/branch-2 branch-2
```

since the `push` step *creates* `branch-2` on origin, after which your Git remembers that their Git has a `branch-2` by creating your own `origin/branch-2`.  (Whew!)

There is a short-cut for this, though.  Instead of typing in two commands, you can use a single command:

```
git push -u origin branch-2
```

The `-u` option here tells `git push` that it should try the push, and—if it succeeds—immediately run `git branch --set-upstream-to` for you.

Once you have done this, `branch-2` has `origin/branch-2` as its upstream, so that when you have `branch-2` checked out, you can run:

```
git push
```

and your `simple` setting for your `push.default` will tell `git push` that it should look up the upstream (`origin/branch-2`) and use that to push your `branch-2` to `origin`'s `branch-2`.

Answer (score 0):

As you already said in your comment.
you used `git push origin master` where origin is your remote-name and master your branch-name. That's the reason why you pushed it to your `master` branch.